# Non-derogatory term equivalent to "artsy-fartsy"

Tags: single-word-requests

"artsy fartsy" can have a loose interpretation, but in this specific case I'm using it as an adjective to describe a person who:

- Considers anyone who isn't invested in humanities/arts a lesser person
- Turns away those interested in art/humanities because their interests do not align with this person's own (e.g. wanting to make a computer game historically and culturally accurate concerning the Spanish, rather than learning the language and/or travelling abroad to Spanish-speaking countries)

I would like to use an equivalent word in a respectful tone, similar to "they're confused" as opposed to "they're idiots". Is there any word or short phrase that can be used, respectfully, *as an adjective* to clearly and concisely communicate the contents of the bullet points above?

"bigot" is pretty descriptive, but is rather derogatory and doesn't imply anything about arts/humanities.

Comment: a 'sophisticate'  comes close ...

Comment: The terms is nearly always hyphenated anyway, but I didn't know until now that there's a [significant US/UK usage split](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=artsy+fartsy%2Carty+farty%2Cartsy-fartsy%2Carty-farty&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cartsy%20fartsy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carty%20farty%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cartsy%20-%20fartsy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carty%20-%20farty%3B%2Cc0) on this one (in BrE it's normally ***arty-farty***, whereas AmE favours the even more "camp" version ***artsy-fartsy***).

Comment: ...interestingly, it's quite the opposite with ***itsy-bitsy, itty-bitty***, where ***BrE*** is far more likely to include an interpolated /s/ in the reduplication.

Comment: The dictionaries give the same pejorative meaning to "arty", that is, affected or ostentatious display. But I personally don't have this association. This makes me wonder what common alternatives there might be for arty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a hard time pronouncing it(which also means it isn't heard much and that only a small % of people would understand it),

but perhaps:

> ***aesthete***
>   [es-theet or, esp. British, ees-]
>
> [Aesthete at Thesaurus.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/aesthete)
>
> 1.
>   a person who has or professes to have refined sensitivity toward the beauties of art or nature.
>
> 2.
>   a person who affects great love of art, music, poetry, etc., and indifference to practical matters.

Answer (score 0):

One could call the subject in question '***A dandy***'

Poet Charles Baudelaire defined the word as "one who elevates aesthetics to a living religion"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandy

An example of when one might use this; "Its just a computer game, you really shouldn't be so concerned with it's historical accuracy. You really are a dandy you know."

Comment: William, the system has flagged your answer for deletion as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. I suggest you [edit] your answer - for example, adding a published definition (linked to the source) and perhaps a sample sentence for *dandy*. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: NB *dandy* is not a proper noun and is therefore not capitalised.